# jQuery hover event not firing on hover

Tags: mouseover, jquery

So if you attach some function on the hover event it won't fire if the mouse is already within th hovering area during page load, and is not moved. You actually have to move the mouse a bit to the event to fire.

Example:

- move the mouse to the hover-effect area
- hit the mouse with an axe
- reload the page with F5

=> hover function not fired :(

Why?

And is there a fix?

Comment: some relevant code posted here wouldn't hurt our feelings ;)

Comment: axe? AFAIK, this is normal behavior. What issues is it causing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected functionality, hover is simply the combination of "mouseOver" and "mouseOut" so if your cursor is over the element on page load, it never technically moves over the element. Unfortunately without a mouse move, there is no way for the javascript to determine the position of the mouse, or the element it is currently over.

Comment: links and css :hover don't behave this way

Comment: css and javascript are different animals, jquerys "hover" is just the closest approximation to css "hover" that is possible with javascript

Comment: Well, there is [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.elementFromPoint). Now you just need the mouse coordinates. From the load event maybe, if this event even has clientX, clientY?

Comment: unfortunately only mouse events return mouse coords, on load the mouse doesn't exist as far as javascript is concerned